# MySQL backup to another database

Tags: mysql

I have a master MySQL server on server X.

I want it to be backed up every N hours to another MySQL server (let's call it Y).

I don't know if it matters, but X is windows server and Y is Ubuntu linux.

I do like the idea of replication, but can I make it work not real time, but once in lets say 4 hours?

Comment: Why not real time? The advantage of replication is that the mirror server is just replaying the same statements. Your main database will hardly notice. Backing up the entire database every 4 hours isn't quite so efficient..

Comment: Curious to hear the answer to the question from @GolezTrol. Note that if you want access to older data, MySQL 5.6 supports [delayed replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html) which allows you to deliberately have the replica lag behind the master. For older MySQL versions `[pt-slave-delay](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-slave-delay.html)` can accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Because Master server is in europe and slave server is in USA. I'm afraid real time will cost latency and slow down the process

Comment: I don't think latency would be much of an issue. If I understand the way replication works, it's more or less sending the binary log over which just contains text queries to be ran on the slaves.

Answer (score 0):

I worked at a place that was afraid of replication due to a previously-botched installation.

They still had binary logging in place, so I would FLUSH the binary logs, copy them to the second server, extract the statements with mysqlbinlog, and apply them to the second database.

You can control how often all of this happens, how much of your bandwidth the file copy consumes, etc.

Plus, if you want to switch to "real" replication, it's easy!

Good luck.